# Error with automated mail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a piece of code that will email me the results of some queries twice a day from SQL Server 2016. When I run this bit of code from my developer window, it works fine. When I run it from the job, I get this error:

> Executed as user: myDB\svcAGCRM2016_PRD. Failed to initialize sqlcmd
>   library with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050).
>   The step failed.

This is the code that runs:

```
declare @recipient_name varchar(500)
declare @SqlQuery varchar(max)

SET @SqlQuery='exec [myDB].[dbo].[sp_DailyRejectionRate]'
set @recipient_name = 'myemail@email.com'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'SMTPProfile',
            @recipients =@recipient_name,
            @subject = '[INFO]'
            ,@query='exec [myDB].[dbo].[sp_DailyRejectionRate];
```

I'm running this from a service account. Weirdly, not with the name of the service account in the error. Actually, I can't even find that account.
In the code, I'm doing an exec because otherwise the query is too long for query.
The service account that runs this is an SA. Also, I wrote another query this morning that sends out email with not problems today.

Any ideas?

Comment: Slightly off topic but....https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0):

What if you explicitly specify the user in the query string?

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name = 'SMTPProfile',
        @recipients =@recipient_name,
        @subject = '[INFO]'
        ,@query='execute as user='my_sa_user' exec [myDB].[dbo].[sp_DailyRejectionRate];
```